# Android application can't extract information from website, throws exception

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get my android application to connect to a website. The code I use works in Java, so that can't be the problem. I've tried finding solutions on here but nothing seems to work. I've tried:

1) Adding internet permission to the manifest

2) Putting the code on a new thread, because network connections are apparently not allowed on the main UI thread.

3) Trying to fiddle with the wifi options on the emulator

Inevitably I run into the exception: "Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)"

Here is my code snippet:

```
private void getPriceFromWeb() {
    final String priceStr;
    double priceDouble;
    Document website = null;
    try {
        website = Jsoup.connect("https://blockchain.info/ticker").ignoreContentType(true).get();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
```

I'm at a loss right now. Any suggestions welcome. Once again, the actual code works if I run it as a normal java program, but doesn't work as an android application. It's very frustrating.

Here is the stack trace:

```
 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
 D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
 W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "blockchain.info": No address associated with hostname
 W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:125)
 W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
 W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:187)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:156)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:98)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:345)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
 W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:652)
 W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:629)
 W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:261)
 W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:250)
 W/System.err:     at com.example.Unutuku.paymenrequestqr.QRrequest.getPriceFromWeb(QRrequest.java:59)
 W/System.err:     at com.example.Unutuku.paymenrequestqr.QRrequest.access$000(QRrequest.java:19)
 W/System.err:     at com.example.Unutuku.paymenrequestqr.QRrequest$2.run(QRrequest.java:47)
 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
 W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
 W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:106)
 W/System.err:  ... 21 more
 I/System.out: EXCEPTION!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: There might be a problem with your phone. Try your code in a different phone or an emulator.

Comment: no, sadly that doesn't work. other emulators are the same, and if I run it on my actual phone via USB the app crashes (stops working).

Comment: Post your stack trace of crash.

Comment: added the stack trace above

Comment: Looks like there's a problem with your internet connection or dns server.

Comment: You are using 37 exclamation marks when you need to use 38. :) kidding, sorry :)

Comment: Seriously though, its doing a IPv6 DNS lookup for blockchain.info - i did a lookup and can see it has no AAAA record (v6) but it does have A records (v4). I'm not sure why it isn't defaulting to v4

Comment: Unless it did try v4 first and its simply an internet connection issue